# How can i call aria-label if it start with "Example"

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-frontend

I'm trying to solve this puzzle.

I have this script:

```
$('button[aria-label="Exam"]').trigger('click');
```

But I need to get also all those that start with Exam for example "Exam 1" or "Exam 202".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that ***selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string***.

```
$('button[aria-label^="Exam"]').trigger('click');
```